# Vue, Jest, Axios.create(), and Modularized API Methods. How to Spy?

Tags: vue.js, axios, jestjs

I'm testing a Vue component, that has a `method()` that calls a Module with Axios, that calls another.

The method inside the component looks like:

```js
 // Component.vue 

 methods: {
   myMethod(){
     return MyAPI.orders
                .exportData(requestData)
                .then(() =>{
                    this.showExportModal();
                });
}
    ...
```

The MyAPI.js looks like:

```js
export const apiClient = axios.create({
    baseURL: `${baseUrl}/api/v2/`,
    headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
});
const methods = {
    orders: {
        exportData(payload) {
            return apiClient
                .post('export',payload)
```

While this works perfectly fine, I do not find a way to test the component properly without creating an ad hoc mock for it.

I'm trying to use `Jest.createMockFromModule` but no luck using it this way:

```js
// test.spec.js
const myAPI = jest.createMockFromModule('../services/myAPI');
const wrapper = shallowMount(ExportOrdersButton, {
    store,
    i18n,
});

[...]

it('should trigger a network request when clicked', async () => {
        const button = wrapper.find('button').element;
        button.click();
        await Vue.nextTick()
        expect(myAPI.default.orders.exportData).toHaveBeenCalled()
    });
```

But despite the method is called, the test does not see it:

```
 Expected number of calls: >= 1
 Received number of calls:    0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`jest.createMockFromModule()` doesn't automatically override imports, but [`jest.mock()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options) does.

Mock the target module (i.e., `MyApi.js`) with a factory that returns the mock object, and then `require` it in the test to access the mock:

```js
jest.mock('../services/MyApi', () => ({
  orders: {
    exportData: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve())
  }
}))

describe('Testing component', () => {
  it('click directive', async () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(ExportOrdersButton)
    await wrapper.find('button').trigger('click')
    expect(require('../services/MyApi').orders.exportData).toHaveBeenCalled()
  })
})
```